# Is there a generic way to retry ansible jobs that get failed?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I observed that usually ansible sets `failed: true` inside the result (`register: result`) for failed tasks.

Still, I also observed that this does not set `failed: false` for successful tasks so I cannot use `until: not result.failed`.

This makes me think that this should work:

```
until: 'failed' not in result or not result.failed
restries: 3
delay: 30
```

So, is this the only **generic** way retry ansible tasks?

Answer (score 2):

There are `failed`/`failure` and `success`/`succeeded` filters.

You can use `until: result | success`